# Can't delete Connected App

Tags: connected-apps

In an attempt to troubleshoot an issue I created a couple of connected apps. I would now like to remove them. But I only have an Edit link and a Manage link.

I am logged in as a System Administrator with full permissions. It is a sandbox org.

Also the connected app that is part of my installed package is not listed in the connected App section. Is this normal?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer, there is no delete button or link on the list of Connected Apps or on the Connected App edit form

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to delete the Connected App by going into the app itself:

Setup -> Create -> Apps -> Click on the Connected App -> Delete

Comment: It's important to remember that you can view the Connected Apps in two places in Salesforce setup, but you can only delete from the Create -> Apps page, not the Manage Apps -> Connected Apps page. If you go to the latter, you will only see an Edit button.

Comment: Just saved my frustration ...

Comment: For me the confusion here was due to the fact that (it appears) you are unable to delete Connected Apps if you have Lightning Experience enabled. Only if you turn *OFF* Lightning Experience are you able to find the DELETE button for Connected Apps.

Super annoying/frustrating and not the first time the Lightning Experience has done this. =/ Anyhow ... FYI in case anyone else was banging their head on this.

Comment: **Important:** Switch to Classic! And then follow benedwards44's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Setup --> Apps Manager --> From the apps list, choose the dropdown for your app and click View, then on the view click the delete button, and once more click delete to confirm.

Comment: ^ For Lightning

Answer (score -1):

I also had this same problem to. I am looking to remove some Docusign App Launchers that I wanted to reconfigure.

This is how I removed the apps.

1. Switch to Salesforce Classic
2. Find Installed Packages from Build> Installed Packages
3. Find the app and follow the prompts to remove the app.

[image: Installed Packages]

Comment: This question was asking about connected apps, not un/managed packages. This looks like a decent answer, just not one that's relevant to _this_ particular question.